# Encontrar el mayor número de una lista de forma recursiva

Tags: python, lista, algoritmos

¿Cómo consigo saber el mayor número de una lista en Python de forma recursiva?

Comment: Hola Ale, bienvenida a **Stack Overflow en Español** ¿Podrías añadir más información? ¿El mayor de qué? de 2 de 3, 4, 5... números ¿Que has intentado?¿Cual es tu código?, por favor edita tu pregunta para ser más especifica.

Comment: Mira ingreso una lista por ejemplo [24,78,4,67] y de ahí que salga el número mayor de esa lista

Comment: Lee la págian [ask], y luego intenta reformurlar la pregunta para evitar que sea cerrada

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Podría servirte esta funcion si lo ejecutas en python 2.7, de manera recursiva busca el máximo de una lista de números, ingresados por el usuario.

```
def Max(list):
    if len(list) == 1:
        return list[0]
    else:
        m = Max(list[1:])
        return m if m > list[0] else list[0]

def main():
    list = eval(raw_input(" ingrese una lista de numeros: "))
    print("el mayor es: ", Max(list))


main()
```